# what is inside $conf in typo3 extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am reading typo3 extension file, and saw below codes:

```
function main($content, $conf) {

        $this->conf = $conf;
        $this->pi_setPiVarDefaults();
        $this->pi_loadLL();
        $this->template = $this->cObj->fileResource($this->conf['templateFile']);
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->set_no_cache();
```

I used `var_dump($conf);` to output `$conf`, it shows:

```
array(53) { ["includeLibs"]=> string(47) "typo3conf/ext/jc_job/pi1/class.tx_jcjob_pi1.php" ["userFunc"]=> string(18) "tx_jcjob_pi1->main" ["templateFile"]=> string(28) "EXT:jc_job/pi1/template.html" ["pidList"]=> string(1) "7" ["code"]=> string(4)...
```

From the result, I can tell some configurations are from this file: `ext_typoscript_setup.txt`, but some not.

SO my question is:

what is inside `$conf`? or what files compose  `$conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end result of `$conf` is essentially Typoscript from `plugin.tx_yourextension_pi1`.

This will be what is in `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` of your extension, plus any changes made along the way. For example in the main template, you can also make changes to the plugin's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your Plugin is configured via:

```
plugin.tx_yourextension_pi1 {
   # these values will you have in $conf
   someValue = well where it goes?
   wrap = wrap|me
   something {
     different = 1
   }
}
```

So $conf will look like this:

```
  $conf = array(
    'someValue' => 'well where it goes?',
    'wrap' => 'wrap|me',
    'something.' => array(
      'different' => '1',
    )
  )
```