# typo3 extension: issue with RTE

Tags: typo3

I am reading one extension, and see below codes:

```
case 'description':
case 'requirement':
  $markerArray['###JOB_'.strtoupper($item).'###'] = $this->cObj->stdWrap($insertArray[$item], $this->conf['view.']);
break;
```

when I run `var_dump($this->conf['view.'])`; it shows: `array(1) { ["parseFunc"]=> string(19) "< lib.parseFunc_RTE" }`

when I check ext_typoscript_setup.txt, the setting is:

```
view {
        parseFunc < tt_content.text.20.parseFunc
    }
```

So my question is:

1. when I run `var_dump($this->conf['view.'])`; why it shows: `array(1) { ["parseFunc"]=> string(19) "< lib.parseFunc_RTE" }`, not show something like `array(1) { ["parseFunc"]=> string(19) "< tt_content.text.20.parseFunc" }`
2. what does this function `array(1) { ["parseFunc"]=> string(19) "< lib.parseFunc_RTE" }` do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) As already mentioned in an answer to another [question you have asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871474/what-is-inside-conf-in-typo3-extension), the typoscript can be defined in various locations, not just in this one setup file. So the value is probably overwritten somewhere else. You can find out where by using the [template analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914863/typo3-extension-how-to-find-certain-ts-setting).

2.) You can use the typoscript object browser (web->template in the backend) to see which typoscript settings are included in the `lib.xyz` objects. Essentially, this very object holds the configuration that is used when content is read from a "RTE text" type field and printed out in the frontend of the website. For example: When you save an RTE content field in the backend, the `<p>` tags are removed, so you won't find them in the database. When the content is read for printing it out, those tags are added again (`<p class="bodytext">`). In this step (through the configuration object), you can influence the rendering of certain things as you need them (like changing the default class name `bodytext` to something else).